# Button built from ListView.builder seems to call the same function for all buttons built from the ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, state, flutter-web, flutter-listview

Basically, I have two nested `ListView`. Builders inside a third `ListView` builder. The two nested listview builders build two rows of custom buttons; the contents of the second row of buttons depend on the selected button in the two rows. The first row works entirely as intended, but the second row causes an issue.

Whenever a button from the second row is pressed, it affects the state of all the other buttons (and the data those lists are built on), as if calling the same function on all elements on the list. The strangest thing, though, is that it only seems to call PART of that function:

```
  void toggleSubcategoryPanelButton(int panelNum, int subCategoryIndex) {
    App()
            .panelNames[panelNum]
            .panelSettings
            .categories[
                App().panelNames[panelNum].panelSettings.activeCategoryIndex]
            .activeSubcategory =
        App()
            .panelNames[panelNum]
            .panelSettings
            .categories[
                App().panelNames[panelNum].panelSettings.activeCategoryIndex]
            .subcategories[subCategoryIndex];

    rerollName(panelNum);
    saveSettingstoPrefs();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

`App()` is a singleton that holds pretty much all the data for this lightweight app. The purpose of this function is to set a new index for `activeSubcategory` for only the 'panel' from which the function was called (given via `panelNum`). Instead, the function sets `activeSubcategory` of to the same index for **all** of the elements of `panelNames` in their `categories` at the current `activeCategoryIndex`.

Then, `rerollName()` seems to only be called for the `panelNum` provided.

The problem can be seen here. The top row's selection is set correctly.

[![Different function][1]][1]

You can (hopefully) see in this gif that the application correctly identifies the `panelNum` as it is displayed in the terminal (index of 1).

The `ListView` in question:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 30.0,
    child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics:
          const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: widget
          .panelSettings
          .categories[widget.panelSettings
              .activeCategoryIndex]
          .subcategories
          .length,
      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
        return Consumer(
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            return PanelButtonToggleable(
              icon: widget
                  .panelSettings
                  .categories[widget
                      .panelSettings
                      .activeCategoryIndex]
                  .subcategories[index]
                  .icon,
              tooltip: widget
                  .panelSettings
                  .categories[widget
                      .panelSettings
                      .activeCategoryIndex]
                  .subcategories[index]
                  .getName(),
              buttonBehavior: () =>
                  _onToggleSubcategoryClick(
                      index),
              toggled: widget
                      .panelSettings
                      .categories[widget
                          .panelSettings
                          .activeCategoryIndex]
                      .subcategories[index]
                      .getName() ==
                  widget
                      .panelSettings
                      .categories[widget
                          .panelSettings
                          .activeCategoryIndex]
                      .activeSubcategory
                      .getName(),
            );
          },
        );
      }),
    ),
  ),

https://github.com/trevclaridge/Name-Generator-Extension


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2tg8.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my issue actually had nothing to do with the `ListView`s at all. Rather the objects pointed to by `widget.panelSettings.categories` were actually the same instance of a `List`. Thus, assigning the entry for `activeSubcategory` was assigning it for all the objects that pointed to the `categories` list.

Confirm this in your own projects using Dart's `identical` method. [Link here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/identical.html).

To solve this, I created a new class `Categories` with an empty constructor to hold the list, so every initialization of the list was from a new object.